# /usr/bin/make: no such file or directory

Tags: makefile

I recently installed Mac OS X on my system.  This is probably a very basic question but when I run `make` it says `make not found` and there is no `make` under `usr/bin`. How to correct this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to get `make`, `gcc` and so on is to install Xcode (this can be found on the 'Applications' DVD that came with your computer, or you can download it from the Apple website, or you can download it from the App Store).

However, the Apple versions of those packages are old - you can use MacPorts to get newer, improved versions of those.

Comment: On Lion, it is available from the App Store for free.